# Google Analytics displaying unwanted hash mark after URL

Tags: google-analytics, dashboard

I have a problem with GA displaying 2 different URLs formats for the same URL.

In the real-time dashboard, it displays correctly [image: URLs without hash mark]

Instead, in the All website data view the URLs display with a hash mark and number after

[image: URL with hash mark]

GA should display just the variant letter 'e' or 'f', I don't understand from where that # gets appended.

PS there are not active filters and the real-time dashboard displays the correct URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you check both view and account level filters?

Comment: Seems like a filter to me as well but I can't see any in the account. What could mean that hash mark?